# Privilege Escalation & Session Hijacking in Identity MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I am using asp.net identity 2.0 for authentication(Owin middleware) in my application.
Session hijacking:
When i login Identity creates AspNet.ApplicationCookie.then,I copied AspNet.ApplicationCookie value.Then i logged out from the application.After Logout,I am creating cookie manually(AspNet.ApplicationCookie) and do a refresh It redirects me home page.

Privilege Escalation:
At the same time i logged in as a User A.I copied(AspNet.ApplicationCookie) his cookie and the i logged out.After i logged in as a User B.I am editing User B Cookie and pasted User A cookie and saved it.After I refreshed the browser I can get UserA access and authentication.

I am clearing all the session and and delete all the cookies When i logged out.Even Asp.Net identity(Owin) generates new AspNet.ApplicationCookie each and every time.But still it accepts old cookies and give me a access.I don't know why? 
Can any one give me how to invalidate old AspNet.ApplicationCookie after log out.
This  is my code in Startup.Auth.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


    }
```

//This is logout code

```
    public ActionResult LogOff ( )
    {
        //Delete all cookies while user log out
        string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
        foreach ( var cookies in myCookies )
        {
            Response.Cookies[ cookies ].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        }
        Request.GetOwinContext( ).Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // AuthenticationManager.SignOut( );
        Session.Clear( );
        Session.RemoveAll( );
        Session.Abandon( );
        return RedirectToAction("LoginPage", "Account");
    }
```

//This is my login controller code

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Allowing you to be signed-in from multiple browsers and log-out only in the browser where you have clicked the "log-out" and not all the other browsers.

But on log-out you can update `SecurityStamp` on the user, and then set up security stamp validation period for a very low period of time.

This will change security stamp:

```
await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
```

put this in your logout method.

And in your `Startup.Auth.cs` modify `UseCookieAuthentication` in this way:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), // set this low enough to optimise between speed and DB performance
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
    }
});
```

The only drawback with this approach - when logout procedure is not executed - nothing happens. And when logout happens, it logs out all other sessions.